# get substring from last index of character

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the substring of all the characters after the last index of /

for example: "www.example.com/sfs3/dd/423"

desired output = 423

I've tried:

```
if let range = link.rangeOfString("/") 
{
//does not give me the last index of / it gives me starting from the first /
 newlink = link.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your syntax you can use the `.BackwardsSearch` option

```
if let range = link.rangeOfString("/", options: .BackwardsSearch) {
    let newlink = link.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
}
```

Alternatively

```
if let newlink = link.componentsSeparatedByString("/").last {
    print(newlink)
}
```

Edit: But I'd prefer the `NSURL` solution suggested by fabian.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `NSURL`'s `-lastPathComponent`:

```
let link = "www.example.com/sfs3/dd/423"
if let url = NSURL(string: link) {
    let newLink = url.lastPathComponent
    // ...
}
```

This is probably the most bullet proof way if your input is a URL, be it from the web or from a local file.